# Application autostart after system boot for a random interval in Linux

Tags: linux, sleep, startup, autostart

Reading 'sleep' mans and googling haven't provide any useful information.

I want to run Pidgin after Ubuntu boots, but after some time left. For example, logon is passed, and after interval for 1 to 5 minutes Pidgin starts. As manuals of 'sleep' says, there a way to specify only number of hours, mins and seconds.

Is there any way/other linux command to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look like you could use linux `at` command. Create a bash script containing something like this, replacing `/path/to/pidgin` with your actual path (you can run `$ whereis pidgin` to find out the location):

```
at now + 5 min <<_EOF_
DISPLAY=:0.0 /path/to/pidgin
_EOF_
```

check out [Files and scripts that execute on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036/files-and-scripts-that-execute-on-boot) to see where you can place that file.

`cron` would be another option

Comment: Forgot about cron! Thanks! Now i think problem is soved.